# Deleting from .net gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

Im looking to programmatically delete from a `GridView`.

I have implemented the gridview's `OnRowDeleting="Delete_Record"` event handler, and this is called when the user clicks the delete link on the GridView, but as the row doesn't seem to be selected the code which does the delete does not work.

To test further I can click select, to select the row (commenting out the code behind the select) then if I click delete the code runs fine.

Is there a way to have the row selected as the first step in the `Delete_Record`?

```
GridViewRow row = gvResults.SelectedRow;
string id = row.Cells[1].Text;

ASB_DataDataContext db = new ASB_DataDataContext();
var delCase = from dc in db.Inputts
              where dc.counter == Convert.ToInt32(id)
              select dc;

foreach (var nCase in delCase)
{
    db.Inputts.DeleteOnSubmit(nCase);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the event you should be having the required index as part of the `GridViewDeleteEventArgs e` which should be like say `e.RowIndex`

you can then access your needed parameter as `grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text`

Comment: Ahhh, thanks for that - had tried something along those lines but had EventArgs rather than GridViewDeleteEventArgs - doh!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by the code shown below

```
public void GridView1_Delete_Record (Object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    string id = gridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text;

    ASB_DataDataContext db = new ASB_DataDataContext();
    var delCase = from dc in db.Inputts
              where dc.counter == Convert.ToInt32(id)
              select dc;

    foreach (var nCase in delCase)
    {
       db.Inputts.DeleteOnSubmit(nCase);
       db.SubmitChanges();
    }  Message.Text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `db.Inputts` as DataSource of your datagrid. Just add next two lines after your code:

```
datagridView1.DataSource = null;
datagridView1.DataSource = db.Inputts;
```

Setting datasource to null is for clearing previous data from datagrid;